# Modify cursor limits

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu-14.04, screen, xfce, multiscreen

I'm working on a script that allows me to control my laptop and PC with the same mouse. Like with multiple screens connected to the same PC, when I drag the cursor off the laptop screen it should appear on the PC's screen. However, I can't figure out, how to allow the cursor to be dragged off screen.
My goal looks like the following(The blue area is the laptop screen, and the black border the border of the cursor "workspace"):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v28HV.png)